# Gale-Shapley algorithm not functioning properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

So I'm trying to code up the Gale-Shapley algorithm in Python, where men propose to women (ideally, the sexes can be reversed). I organized all men, women, and rankings in one dictionary, where the men/women are the keys, and their rankings are the values (as a list). Thus I have a test dictionary that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

dic = {'m1': ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', math.nan],
 'm2': ['w4', 'w3', 'w2', 'w1', math.nan],
 'm3': ['w4', 'w3', 'w1', 'w2', math.nan],
 'm4': ['w1', 'w4', 'w3', 'w2', math.nan],
 'm5': ['w1', 'w2', 'w4', math.nan, math.nan],
 'w1': ['m2', 'm3', 'm1', 'm4', 'm5'],
 'w2': ['m3', 'm1', 'm2', 'm4', 'm5'],
 'w3': ['m5', 'm4', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3'],
 'w4': ['m1', 'm4', 'm5', 'm2', 'm3']}
```

So printing the dictionary gives

```
{'m1': ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', nan],
 'm2': ['w4', 'w3', 'w2', 'w1', nan],
 'm3': ['w4', 'w3', 'w1', 'w2', nan],
 'm4': ['w1', 'w4', 'w3', 'w2', nan],
 'm5': ['w1', 'w2', 'w4', nan, nan],
 'w1': ['m2', 'm3', 'm1', 'm4', 'm5'],
 'w2': ['m3', 'm1', 'm2', 'm4', 'm5'],
 'w3': ['m5', 'm4', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3'],
 'w4': ['m1', 'm4', 'm5', 'm2', 'm3']}
```

Then my algorithm looks like this:

```
couples = [] #initialize list of marriages

#men-proposing algorithm
#for women-proposing, switch the ""'m' in man" to "'w' in man"

#this for loop does one round of proposals/rejections, until men's rankings are exhausted
for man, ranks in dic.items():
    if man in [tup[0] for tup in couples]: #check man isn't already engaged
        continue #go to next man if engaged
    else:
        if 'm' in man: #ensure it's a man
            if not pd.isna(ranks[0]): #check man hasn't already proposed to everyone on his list
                w = ranks[0]
                ranks.pop(0)
                engage = (man,w)
                sub_cup = [tup for tup in couples if tup[1] == w]
                if sub_cup: #check if woman is already engaged
                    other_man = sub_cup[0][0]
                    if dic[w].index(other_man) > dic[w].index(man): #if man is preferred to other man
                        couples.remove(sub_cup[0])
                        couples.append(engage)
                else: #unconditionally add couple if woman isn't engaged
                    couples.append(engage)
```

The problem, however, is that already-engaged men are proposing to women. In the algorithm, if a man is engaged, he's supposed to not make a proposal. So Round 1 works perfectly, and we have, as the couples:

```
[('m1', 'w1'), ('m2', 'w4')]
```

and the new dictionary is:

```
{'m1': ['w2', 'w3', 'w4', nan],
 'm2': ['w3', 'w2', 'w1', nan],
 'm3': ['w3', 'w1', 'w2', nan],
 'm4': ['w4', 'w3', 'w2', nan],
 'm5': ['w2', 'w4', nan, nan],
 'w1': ['m2', 'm3', 'm1', 'm4', 'm5'],
 'w2': ['m3', 'm1', 'm2', 'm4', 'm5'],
 'w3': ['m5', 'm4', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3'],
 'w4': ['m1', 'm4', 'm5', 'm2', 'm3']}
```

So in Round 2, only men 3, 4, and 5 are supposed to make proposals. But when I run the for loop again, everyone makes a proposal, as evidenced by how the dictionary is altered:

```
{'m1': ['w3', 'w4', nan],
 'm2': ['w2', 'w1', nan],
 'm3': ['w1', 'w2', nan],
 'm4': ['w3', 'w2', nan],
 'm5': ['w4', nan, nan],
 'w1': ['m2', 'm3', 'm1', 'm4', 'm5'],
 'w2': ['m3', 'm1', 'm2', 'm4', 'm5'],
 'w3': ['m5', 'm4', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3'],
 'w4': ['m1', 'm4', 'm5', 'm2', 'm3']}
```

And the new list of couples is

```
[('m1', 'w2'), ('m2', 'w3'), ('m4', 'w4')]
```

which shouldn't happen; m1 shouldn't propose to w2 since he's engaged to w1, and similarly, m2 shouldn't propose to w3.

I thought my initial if-else statement in the for loop ensures only unengaged men make proposals, but it seems that's not the case. Or perhaps something else is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You include the changed preference listing, but what's the value of `couples` after you run the second round?

Comment: Please fix the posted code: one block, including all of your `imports` and tracing `print` statements.  When we paste that single block and run it, we should get output identical to yours.

Comment: Your posted code performs only round 1 -- it doesn't reach the problem point.

Comment: I've tried tossing this into a loop; I don't get the output you claim.  I have a clean execution and a correct solution.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's fixed now (and I cleaned the code so the original error should be reproducible)! I realized that every time I ran the loop, I re-initialized the list of couples, so whenever the code checked if a man was in the list of couples, the man would never be in it.